# Mounting zpool (Solaris server and Freebsd client)

Tags: freebsd, solaris, nfs, zfs

I have a Solaris with ZFS file system and NFS. I am kind of lost on how to export directories from the Solaris OS which has zfs via NFS? That way I can mount them on Freebsd client.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sharenfs` property.  e.g.

```
zfs set sharenfs=on filesystem
```

From the solaris `zfs` man page (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/6mbb1kqo8/index.html)

> sharenfs=on | off | opts
>
> Controls whether the file system is shared
>   over NFS, and what options are used. A file system with a sharenfs
>   property of off is managed through traditional tools such as
>   share(1M), unshare(1M), and dfstab(4). Otherwise, the file system is
>   automatically shared and unshared with the zfs share and zfs unshare
>   commands. If the property is set to on, the share(1M) command is
>   invoked with no options. Otherwise, the share(1M) command is invoked
>   with options equivalent to the contents of this property.
>
> When the sharenfs property is changed for a dataset, the dataset and
>   any children inheriting the property are re-shared with the new
>   options, only if the property was previously off, or if they were
>   shared before the property was changed. If the new property is off,
>   the file systems are unshared.

Comment: I did it but the client still disable  : svcs -a|grep nfs
disabled       Apr_22   svc:/network/nfs/cbd:default
disabled       Apr_22   svc:/network/nfs/client:default
disabled       Apr_22   svc:/network/nfs/log:default
online         Apr_22   svc:/network/nfs/server:default
online         Apr_22   svc:/network/nfs/status:default
online         Apr_22   svc:/network/nfs/nlockmgr:default
online         19:44:30 svc:/network/nfs/mapid:default
online         19:44:30 svc:/network/nfs/rquota:default

Comment: that's a different problem with a different solution.  you need to enable the nfs service.  i'm not a solaris expert but google suggests that maybe you should try `svcadm -v enable network/nfs/serve`

Comment: yes I find it :svcadm enable network/nfs/client:default. I will try again

Comment: you need to enable the NFS server, not the client.  `network/nfs/server` (i accidentally missed the `r` on my last comment).  You don't say what version of Solaris you are running but the following URL documents the procedure for Solaris 10 Jet: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19118-01/n1.sprovsys52/819-6519/gclho/index.html - i doubt if it's changed much (if at all) since then.

Comment: yes the server is running, and all the services now are online. But `zfs set share=name=pr,path=/pr,prot=nfs rpool/pr`
`cannot set property for 'rpool/pr': invalid property 'share' ` why does it give me this error?

Comment: The property is called `sharenfs`, not just `share`.

Comment: well, it still the same. I don't know how to mount it

Comment: Once you get it shared, and verify that it's shared(`share`), you'd mount it as a NFS filesystem on the NFS client to a mount point.

Answer (score 0):

Appears like you've gotten advice on how to share it on the Solaris side.  Running `share` on the server will show what is shared (and a few new methods with Solaris 11).

Then just mount it on the client, for a one time mount:
`mount -F nfs <server>:/share_path  /mount_point_path`
Or added it to the vfstab or set to mount via the automounter.